# Laravel Error: Details blade displays wrong data, displays previous column data

Tags: php, laravel

[image: Shows different entries with the same {!!$itenary->name!!}]
I have a Details page that displays "short description", "Duration", and "description of tour" from a database.

**Problem:**
Some Data displayed on the blade is from the previous entry in the table

**Question**:
Why would a details blade display data that's from a previous entry?

code snippet for the
`details.blade.php`

page

```
    @extends('client.layout.app2')
    @section('title')

   Flamingo WIld Life Vacation | {{$itenary->name}}

    @endsection
    @section('content')


    <div id="page_caption" class="hasbg parallax  " style="background-image:url('/header_image/{{$itenary->header_image}}');">
    <div class="single_tour_header_content">
    <div class="standard_wrapper">
    <a href="/header_image/{{$itenary->header_image}}" id="single_tour_gallery_open" class="button fancy-gallery"><span class="ti-camera"></span>View Photos</a>
    <div style="display:none;">

    @foreach($images as $image)

    <a id="single_tour_gallery_image1" href="/itenary_images/{{$image->body_image}}" title="The road to success and the road to failure are almost exactly the same" class="fancy-gallery"></a>


    @endforeach


    </div>


    <div class="single_tour_header_price">
    <div class="single_tour_price">

    {{ $itenary->name }}
    </div>

    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Begin content -->
    <div id="page_content_wrapper" class="hasbg ">
    <div class="inner">

    <!-- Begin main content -->
    <div class="inner_wrapper">

    <div class="sidebar_wrapper">

    <div class="sidebar_top"></div>

    <div class="sidebar">

    <div class="content">

    <div class="single_tour_header_price">

    <div class="single_tour_per_person">
     {{$itenary->name}} </div>
    </div>

    <div class="single_tour_booking_wrapper themeborder contact_form7">
    <div role="form" class="wpcf7" id="wpcf7-f142-o1" lang="en-US" dir="ltr">
        <div class="screen-reader-response"></div>
        <form action="#" method="post" class="wpcf7-form" novalidate="novalidate">

            <p>
                <label> Full Name
                    <br />
                    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-name"><input type="text" name="your-name" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="John Doe" /></span> </label>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label> Email Address
                        <br />
                        <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-email"><input type="email" name="your-email" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-email wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-email" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="sample@yourcompany.com" /></span> </label>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <label> Phone Number
                            <br />
                            <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap tel-729"><input type="tel" name="tel-729" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-tel wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-tel" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" /></span> </label>
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <label> Tour Date
                                <br />
                                <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap menu-419">
                                    <select name="menu-419" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-select wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">
                                        <option value="10-18 January 2017">10-18 January 2017</option>
                                        <option value="23-31 January 2017">23-31 January 2017</option>
                                        <option value="7-15 February 2017">7-15 February 2017</option>
                                        <option value="18-26 February 2017">18-26 February 2017</option>
                                    </select>
                                </span>
                            </label>
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <label> Number of Person
                                <br />
                                <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap text-237">
                                    <input type="text" name="text-237" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="1 person" />
                                </span>
                            </label>
                            <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap dynamictourtitle">
                                <input type="hidden" name="dynamictourtitle" value="Grand Switzerland" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7dtx-dynamictext wpcf7-dynamichidden" aria-invalid="false" />
                            </span>
                            <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap dynamictoururl">
                                <input type="hidden" name="dynamictoururl" value="#" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7dtx-dynamictext wpcf7-dynamichidden" aria-invalid="false" />
                            </span>
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <input type="submit" value="Book This Tour" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit" />
                        </p>
                        <div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none"></div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="single_tour_view_wrapper themeborder">
                    <div class="single_tour_view_desc">
                    This tour&#039;s been viewed&nbsp;544&nbsp;times in the past week </div>

                    <div class="single_tour_view_icon ti-alarm-clock"></div>
                </div>
                <br class="clear" />
            </div>

            <!--  <a id="single_tour_share_button" href="javascript:;" class="button ghost themeborder"><span class="ti-email"></span>Share this tour</a> -->
            <div class="one withsmallpadding ppb_text" style="text-align:left;padding:30px 0 30px 0;">
                <div class="standard_wrapper">
                    <div class="page_content_wrapper">
                        <div class="inner">
                            <div style="margin:auto;width:100%">
                            </p>
                            <h5 class="space">Share "{{$itenary->name}}" Itenary on:</h5>
                            <div class="social_wrapper shortcode light small">
                                <ul>
                                    <li class="facebook"><a target="_blank" title="Facebook" href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                                    <li class="twitter"><a target="_blank" title="Twitter" href="https://twitter.com/#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                                    <li class="Whatsapp"><a target="_blank" title="Whatsapp" href="#"><i class="fa fa-whatsapp"></i></a></li>


                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <ul class="sidebar_widget">
            <li id="text-3" class="widget widget_text">
                <h2 class="widgettitle">For More Informations</h2>
                <div class="textwidget"><span class="ti-mobile" style="margin-right:10px;"></span>+254722230053
                    <br/>
                    <span class="ti-alarm-clock" style="margin-right:10px;"></span>Mon - Sat 8.00 - 18.00</div>
                </li>
                <li id="grandtour_tour_posts-11" class="widget Grandtour_Tour_Posts">
                    <h2 class="widgettitle"></h2>

                    @foreach($itenaries->take(3) as $itenary)
                    <div class="one gallery1 grid static filterable portfolio_type themeborder" style="background-image:url('/header_image/{{$itenary->header_image}}');">
                        <a class="tour_image" href="#"></a>
                        <div class="portfolio_info_wrapper">
               <!--  <div class="tour_price ">
               $6,000 </div> -->
               <h5>{{$itenary->name}}</h5>
               <div class="tour_attribute_wrapper">
                <div class="tour_attribute_rating">
                    <div class="br-theme-fontawesome-stars-o">
                        <div class="br-widget">
                            <a href="javascript:;" class="br-selected"></a>
                            <a href="javascript:;" class="br-selected"></a>
                            <a href="javascript:;" class="br-selected"></a>
                            <a href="javascript:;" class="br-selected"></a>
                            <a href="javascript:;"></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <br class="clear" />
    @endforeach

    </li>
    </ul>

    <div class="single_tour_users_online_wrapper themeborder">
    <div class="single_tour_users_online_icon">
    <span class="ti-info-alt"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="single_tour_users_online_content">
    <strong>131</strong> traveler(s) are considering our tours right now! </div>
    </div>

    </div>

    </div>
    <br class="clear" />

    <div class="sidebar_bottom"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar_content ">

    <h1>{{$itenary->name}}</h1>
    <div class="single_tour_attribute_wrapper themeborder ">
    <div class="one_fourth">
    <div class="tour_attribute_icon ti-time"></div>
    <div class="tour_attribute_content">
    {{$itenary->duration}} </div>
    </div>

    <div class="one_fourth">
    <div class="tour_attribute_icon ti-id-badge"></div>
    <div class="tour_attribute_content">
    Age 12+ </div>
    </div>

    <div class="one_fourth">
    <div class="tour_attribute_icon ti-calendar"></div>
    <div class="tour_attribute_content">
    Sep,&nbsp;Oct,&nbsp;Nov,&nbsp;Dec </div>
    </div>

    <div class="one_fourth last">
    <div class="tour_attribute_icon ti-user"></div>
    <div class="tour_attribute_content">
    Availability 50 </div>
    </div>

    </div>
    <br class="clear" />
    <p>{!! $itenary->short_description !!}.</p>
    <div class="single_tour_content">
    <p class="p1"> {!! $itenary->description_of_tour !!}.</p>

    </div>
    <div class="fullwidth_comment_wrapper sidebar">

    <div>


    <div class="comment" id="comment-20">


    <div class="right ">



    <a rel='nofollow' class='comment-reply-link' href='#' aria-label='Reply to Jack Dawson'>Reply</a>
    <div class="comment_text" />



    </div>
    </div>
    <br class="clear" />
    </li>
    <!-- #comment-## -->


    <br class="clear" />
    </li>
    <!-- #comment-## -->


    <br class="clear" />
    </li>
    <!-- #comment-## -->


    </div>
    <br class="clear" />
    </li>
    <!-- #comment-## -->
    </div>



    </div>

    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End main content -->

    <br class="clear"/>
    <div class="tour_related">
    <h3 class="sub_title">Similar Tours</h3>
    <div id="portfolio_filter_wrapper" class="gallery classic three_cols portfolio-content section content clearfix" data-columns="3">

    @foreach($itenaries->take(3)  as $itenary)
    <div class="element grid classic3_cols">
    <div class="one_third gallery3 classic static filterable portfolio_type themeborder" data-id="post-171">

    <a class="tour_image" href="#">
    <img src="{{asset('header_image/'.$itenary->header_image)}}" alt="{{$itenary->name}}l" />

    <!--  <div class="tour_price has_discount">
    <span class="normal_price">
    $6,000
    </span> $5,900
    </div> -->
    </a>

    <div class="portfolio_info_wrapper">
    <a class="tour_link" href="{{ route('itenaries.show',$itenary->slug) }}"><h4>{{$itenary->name}}</h4></a>
    <div class="tour_excerpt">
    <p>{{$itenary->itenary_category}}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tour_attribute_wrapper">
    <div class="tour_attribute_rating">
    <div class="br-theme-fontawesome-stars-o">
    <div class="br-widget">
    <a href="javascript:;" class="br-selected"></a>
    <a href="javascript:;" class="br-selected"></a>
    <a href="javascript:;" class="br-selected"></a>
    <a href="javascript:;" class="br-selected"></a>
    <a href="javascript:;"></a>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tour_attribute_rating_count">
    4&nbsp; reviews </div>
    </div>

    <div class="tour_attribute_days">
    <span class="ti-time"></span> {{$itenary->duration}} </div>
    </div>
    <br class="clear" />
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    @endforeach

    </div>
    </div>

    </div>
    <br class="clear" />
    </div>

    @endsection
```

`Itenary Controller`

```
    public function show($slug){
    
            $itenary=Itenary::where('slug', $slug)->firstOrFail();
            $images=$itenary->itenary_images;
             $itenaries=Itenary::get();
    
    
    // dd($images);
            return view('client.itenary.details')->with('itenary', $itenary)->with('images', $images)->with('itenaries', $itenaries);
        }
```

I have done `php artisan optimize`,
I have cleared the cache.
but no changes

Comment: Please provide more code, including the controller code.

Comment: @MichaelMano I have included the controller.

Comment: There is a `@foreach($itenaries->take(3) as $itenary)` in the view where you overwrite the `$itenary` variable that you fill in the controller. Could that be the cause? Try renaming one of them.

Comment: @JorisJ1 I have renamed one and it worked. thank you for the assit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `@foreach($itenaries->take(3) as $itenary)` in the view where you overwrite the `$itenary` variable that you fill in the controller.